# ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Azure Web Apps

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, odbc, azure-web-app-service, always-encrypted

I am aware that Microsoft has not specified any plan to support Always Encrypted from within Core through SqlConnection, however, it is supported on ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server (OdbcConnection): [Using Always Encrypted of SQL Server from .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900987/using-always-encrypted-of-sql-server-from-net-core-2-1/53122322)

I am doing two simple queries in my Azrue Web App and I would like to use SQL Server ODBC driver for them. I found answers on SO that it is not supported, but no mention to the SQL Server ODBC specifically.

Is SQL Server ODBC Driver supported on Azure Web Apps? If not, is there any plan to support it or a workaround specific to the SQL Server one to work on Azure Web Apps (say deploying a portable version with the app, for example)?

Comment: No, you can't use [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) on [Microsoft Azure Web App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/), as this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75982c97-1210-491f-a424-49faa4b6601a/azure-app-service-odbc-driver) shows.

Comment: I have seen this answer before, however, I am specifically asking for SQL Server ODBC