# Enable Column Encryption Azure Function App v2 Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure, function

Currently have a number of Azure Functions running on V1 and looking to start to migrate to v2 however i'm running into issues with enable column encryption using via the sqlstringbuilder.

If i comment out the enable column encryption property the function executes fine and returns data that is encrypted.

I need to enable the column encryption property so that it return data that is decrypted.

```
#load "Serialize.csx"

#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Configuration;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
//using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

 string connectionString = @"Data Source = #####################;

SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);


// THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR
connStringBuilder.ColumnEncryptionSetting = SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting.Enabled;

connectionString = connStringBuilder.ConnectionString;



string json =  " ";


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     SqlDataReader dataReader;

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Encrypted5";
     cmd.Connection = conn;

     dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     var r = Serialize(dataReader);

     json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, Formatting.Indented); 


     conn.Close();
}


return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```

}

**Resulting Error Messages when enable:**

2019-11-02T21:30:29.124 [Error] run.csx(29,19): error CS1061: 'SqlConnectionStringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnEncryptionSetting' and no extension method 'ColumnEncryptionSetting' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlConnectionStringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

2019-11-02T21:30:29.295 [Error] run.csx(29,45): error CS0103: The name 'SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting' does not exist in the current context

Comment: According to my research, if you want to use the column encryption with .Net Core, you need to use the sdk ```Microsoft.Data.SqlClient```. For more details, please refer to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, if we want to use the setting `ColumnEncryptionSetting`  to enable  Always Encrypted with . net core, we should use the SDK [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient). For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) and the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible).
For example
My code

```
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string connectionString = @"";

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            connStringBuilder.ColumnEncryptionSetting = SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting.Enabled;

            string str = "";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "select * from dbo.Student";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            str += reader.GetString(0) + "  " + reader.GetString(1) + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return
             (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(str);
        }       
        
    }
```

[image]
[image]

If when you develop the function, you meet the error `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform`. Please add the following script to the csproj file. For more details, please refer to [document](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-548269445)

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
</Target>
<Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />
</Target>
```

[image]

---

Besides, you also can use the ODBC driver.  The ODBC driver supports Always Encrypted.
For example

```
 using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(
                "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};;Server={server name};Trusted_Connection=yes;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;Database={DBname};"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    Console.WriteLine("SSN: " + Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

For futher details, pleae refer to

[Using Always Encrypted of SQL Server from .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900987/using-always-encrypted-of-sql-server-from-net-core-2-1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=azuresqldb-current

Comment: Thanks a ton for this!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be using System.Data.SqlClient with version 4.5.1 which doesn't have the property for setting column encryption:

[image]

Either you can upgrade the framework for the updated one or you can simply append the setting in connection string itself:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=server63; Initial Catalog=Clinic; Integrated Security=true; Column Encryption Setting=enabled";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Additionally check the below doc for further reference:

[Azure Function - System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952409/azure-function-system-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported-on-this-platform/53952815)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.columnencryptionsetting?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver15

Hope it helps.